# google-cloud-videointelligence - TimeoutError start Oct 5

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I started to get:

```
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: Operation did not complete within the designated timeout.
```

(even for a 5 sec videos & I have timeout=1000)

It started on Oct 5 (before that it work great for months).

What I use:
python:3.8.7 ,pip install google-cloud-videointelligence==2.3.3 ,Google cloud ,running on Cloud Run - python:3.8.7-slim

Code:

```
from google.cloud import videointelligence
video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
context = videointelligence.VideoContext(
            segments=None
    )
features=  [  videointelligence.Feature.LABEL_DETECTION,
            videointelligence.Feature.TEXT_DETECTION,
            videointelligence.Feature.OBJECT_TRACKING]
request = videointelligence.AnnotateVideoRequest(
        input_uri="gs://"+path,
        video_context=context,
        features=features
    )
operation = video_client.annotate_video(request)
result = operation.result(timeout=1000)
result = json.loads(MessageToJson(result._pb))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that you encounter error `concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: Operation did not complete within the designated timeout.` is that you are sending more video material per minute than before and you might be hitting the quota **"Backend time in seconds per minute"** during processing. See [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/quotas#request_quotas) for more information.

Check if you are hitting the quota in Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Quotas and search for "Backend time in seconds per minute". If so, [increase the "Backend time in seconds per minute" quota](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/quotas#quota_increases) to your desired value to increase the number of videos processed in parallel.

Just to add, I was able to reproduce the same error when I hit the quota. Below is the sample image:

[image]

See actual error message when quota was hit:

[image]